# FileSystemException: Creation failed (OS Error: Not a directory, errno = 20)

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I'm trying to convert a web page to pdf file. for that I've been using [webcontent_converter](https://pub.dev/packages/webcontent_converter2) to doing this task.

```
IconButton(
        onPressed: () async {
        var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        var savedPath = (dir.path + "sample.pdf");
              var result = await WebcontentConverter.webUriToPdf(
                 uri:"https://xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxx",
                 savedPath: savedPath,
                 format: PaperFormat.a4,
                 margins:
                     PdfMargins.px(top: 35, bottom: 35, right: 35, left: 35),
                 );
                  await OpenFile.open(result);
                  WebcontentConverter.logger.info(result ?? '');
                  new Directory(result)
                      .create(recursive: true)
                      .then((Directory directory) async {
                    String path = directory.path;
                    File file;
                    file = await File(savedPath).create();
                    file.writeAsStringSync(path);
                  });
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.save),
              ),
```

The pdf is not creating. I need to convert this `WebView` to `pdf` ad download it to download folder.

if there is any other package to do this. please suggest it as well

Answer (score 1):

result is not a path, it looks like it's some type of custom type. Log the return value of `WebcontentConverter.webUriToPdf()` and make sure it's a path. You will need to have the device's persistent storage path as well, this package can help: https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider

And a path should look something like this: `/docs/anotherfolder/somefoldername/file.pdf`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, I think you need to add slash `/` before `sample.pdf`.

`await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();` return is like this (no slash at the end)

```
'/home/user/Documents'
```

So you need to add the slash `/`

```
var savedPath = (dir.path + "/sample.pdf");
```

or you can use join

```
var savedPath = join(dir.path, "sample.pdf");
```